# OpenGL Deferred rendering static?

Tags: c++, opengl, deferred-rendering

I'm trying to implement deferred rendering in my engine but I'm having some problems.
It seems that there is some static in the triangles being drawn.

Here is the drawing code:

```
    // GEOMETRY PASS

    gbuffer->BindForWriting(); // glBind(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
    window->Clear(); // glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // Before it was glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); (I was testing)

    ... // Render all objects (they are rendering well when not using deferred rendering)

    // LIGHTING PASS

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    window->Clear(); // Clear buffer again (same thing above)

    gbuffer->BindForReading(); // glBind(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

    GLsizei HalfWidth = (GLsizei)(window->GetSize().x / 2.0f);
    GLsizei HalfHeight = (GLsizei)(window->GetSize().y / 2.0f); // Get half the size of the window

    gbuffer->SetReadBuffer(GBUFFER_POSITION); // glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
    glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, window->GetSize().x, window->GetSize().y, 0, 0, HalfWidth, HalfHeight, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_LINEAR);

    gbuffer->SetReadBuffer(GBUFFER_DIFFUSE); // glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1);
    glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, window->GetSize().x, window->GetSize().y, 0, HalfHeight, HalfWidth, window->GetSize().y, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_LINEAR);

    gbuffer->SetReadBuffer(GBUFFER_NORMAL); // glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2);
    glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, window->GetSize().x, window->GetSize().y, HalfWidth, HalfHeight, window->GetSize().x, window->GetSize().y, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_LINEAR);

    gbuffer->SetReadBuffer(GBUFFER_TEXCOORD); // glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT3);
    glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, window->GetSize().x, window->GetSize().y, HalfWidth, 0, window->GetSize().x, HalfHeight, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_LINEAR);
```

(upleft is diffuse, upright is normals, downleft is position and downright is texture coords)

[image: Image showing static in triangles]

**EDIT:**
New screenshot after i enabled GL_DEPTH_TEST:

[image]

**EDIT 2**
Here is the GBuffer setup:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

glGenTextures(4, textures);
glGenTextures(1, &depthTexture);

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[i]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB32F, windowSize.x, windowSize.y, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + i, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[i], 0);
}

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F, windowSize.x, windowSize.y, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture, 0);

GLenum drawBuffers[] = {
    GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
    GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1,
    GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2,
    GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT3
};
glDrawBuffers(4, drawBuffers);

GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
if (status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    // PRINT ERROR TO LOG ( No errors here i've already checked)
    return;
}

glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

**EDIT 3** I'm following [this tutorial](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial35/tutorial35.html) if it helps in anything

Comment: Is there a reason for disabling the depth-test before writing to the gbuffers? The results look to me as if triangles from the back are drawn over triangles from the front side.

Comment: Oh i just had it on before, but i tried putting it off so i could check if it worked that way but the result was pratically the same

Comment: I will edit the answer and update with a new image

Comment: Can you also add the gbuffer setup?

Comment: Oh sure, i've already updaten the question

Comment: This is a stab in the dark, but I often get similar patterns when reading from a texture that is currently bound as depth attachment(even when not actually writing to it). Examining your code, this does not seem to happen, however I'm not sure I totally follow what you do, so I thought I'd comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to disable GL_BLEND before drawing the objects in the buffer.

Now it's working fine.

```
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
(Deferred rendering...)
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
```

Comment: `+1` It's always good practice to answer one's own question when a solution has been found! Any thoughts on [OpenGL strange shadows on a simple cube-like object](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/5649/5846)? I can move the question to SO if it helps.

Comment: @uhoh can you move that question to SO, I'm unable to comment on CG.

Comment: Done! [OpenGL strange shadows on a simple cube-like object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47119517/3904031)