# OpenGL strange shadows on a simple cube-like object

Tags: python-2.7, opengl

**EDIT:** I could not follow the comments about shared vertices, so I rewrote the script using OpenGL's automatic cube generation `glutSolidCube()` method instead of building the object by hand. The same strange pattern appears, indicating the problem was not related to my construction.

---

I'm trying to use OpenGL on my laptop to rotate a cube-like object according to real-time data based on [this script](http://blog.bitify.co.uk/2013/11/3d-opengl-visualisation-of-data-from.html), but I keep getting this strange shadow-like artifact.

The script below is a subset of the script in the post but I've rebuilt the vertices so that I (believe that I) understand them.

I can make them disappear by toggling `GL_LIGHTING` but then I loose the lighting. An image of the object is shown in both states below.

I expect my problem is something simple but I can't find a way to solve it by trial and error, can someone help me find what I've done wrong here?

This is OpenGL 3.1.0 running in Python 2.7 on OSX 10.11 in case that makes a difference.

[image: cube image]

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pygame
# import urllib
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from pygame.locals import *
import time
import numpy as np

SCREEN_SIZE = (800, 600)

def resize(width, height):
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluPerspective(45.0, float(width) / height, 0.001, 10.0)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluLookAt(0.0, 1.0, -5.0,
              0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
              0.0, 1.0, 0.0)

def init():
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    # The following don't seem to have any effect, so I've commented out
    # glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    # glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)
    # glEnable(GL_BLEND)
    # glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH)
    # glHint(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST)
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)
    glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, (0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0));

def run():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE, HWSURFACE | OPENGL | DOUBLEBUF)
    resize(*SCREEN_SIZE)
    init()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    x_angle = -30.
    y_angle =  60.

    toggle = True

    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        if toggle:
            toggle = False
            glDisable(GL_LIGHTING)
        else:
            toggle = True
            glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)

        then = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                return
            if event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                return

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        glPushMatrix()
        glRotate(float(x_angle), 1, 0, 0)
        glRotate(float(y_angle), 0, 1, 0)

        glutSolidCube(1.0)
        glColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.7)

        glPopMatrix()
        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

---

Earlier image and script:

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pygame
# import urllib
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from pygame.locals import *
import time
import numpy as np

SCREEN_SIZE = (800, 600)

def resize(width, height):
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluPerspective(45.0, float(width) / height, 0.001, 10.0)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluLookAt(0.0, 1.0, -5.0,
              0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
              0.0, 1.0, 0.0)

def init():
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    # The following don't seem to have any effect, so I've commented out
    # glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    # glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)
    # glEnable(GL_BLEND)
    # glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH)
    # glHint(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST)
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)   # this one
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, (0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0));

def run():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE, HWSURFACE | OPENGL | DOUBLEBUF)
    resize(*SCREEN_SIZE)
    init()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    cube = Cube((0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (.5, .5, .7))

    x_angle = -30.
    y_angle =  60.

    toggle = True

    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        if toggle:
            toggle = False
            glDisable(GL_LIGHTING)
        else:
            toggle = True
            glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)

        then = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                return
            if event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                return

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        glPushMatrix()
        glRotate(float(x_angle), 1, 0, 0)
        glRotate(float(y_angle), 0, 1, 0)
        cube.render()
        glPopMatrix()
        pygame.display.flip()

class Cube(object):

    def __init__(self, position, color):
        self.position = position
        self.color = color

    num_faces = 6

    vertices = [ (-1.0, -0.25,  0.5),
                 ( 1.0, -0.25,  0.5),
                 ( 1.0, -0.25, -0.5),
                 (-1.0, -0.25, -0.5), # bottom y<0
                 (-1.0,  0.25,  0.5),
                 ( 1.0,  0.25,  0.5),
                 ( 1.0,  0.25, -0.5),
                 (-1.0,  0.25,- 0.5) ] # top y>0

    normals = [ ( 0.0, -1.0,  0.0),  # bottom
                ( 0.0, +1.0,  0.0),  # top
                (-1.0,  0.0,  0.0),  # left
                (+1.0,  0.0,  0.0),  # right
                ( 0.0,  0.0, -1.0),  # back
                ( 0.0,  0.0, +1.0) ] # front

    vertex_indices = [ (0, 1, 2, 3),  # bottom
                       (4, 5, 6, 7),  # top
                       (0, 3, 7, 4),  # left
                       (1, 2, 6, 5),  # right
                       (2, 6, 7, 3),  # back
                       (0, 1, 5, 4) ]  # front


    def render(self):
        then = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        glColor(self.color)

        vertices = self.vertices

        glBegin(GL_QUADS)

        for face_no in xrange(self.num_faces):
            glNormal3dv(self.normals[face_no])
            v1, v2, v3, v4 = self.vertex_indices[face_no]
            glVertex(vertices[v1])
            glVertex(vertices[v2])
            glVertex(vertices[v3])
            glVertex(vertices[v4])
        glEnd()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Comment: I'm not very experienced with OpenGL on python, but have you enabled by any chance any form of shadowing, like shadow mapping?

Comment: I'm not so experienced either; so far I've only tried what's shown in the script. I'm happy to try something but please add a link to documentation or spell out the command literally. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried removing `glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)`?

Comment: And what do you expect to do by using `glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)`? You created a shader, but you need to feed it with GLSL source code and attach it to a shader program.

Comment: Here is a good example [source code](http://python-opengl-examples.blogspot.pt/2009/04/basic-shading.html) you can analyse.

Comment: @RicardoAntunes OK I will check this out and the blogpost looks very helpful, thank you! That line was a "left-over" and only present in one of the two scripts I've posted. No change after deletion. As I mentioned in the question, I've started from a script posted in a blog (thus all the commented-outlines). I have (a little) more familiarity with Blender, but just starting to try OpenGL.

Comment: You are missing all calls related to material properties and you only set the ambient term of the lightsource. Maybe this helps: http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter05.html

Comment: @Rabbid76 yes I did. There were no answers, so I deleted it and moved it to computer graphics SE. After some weeks there, still with no answers, I moved it back here. Trying to avoid cross-posting. If it is a driver issue, it is possible I'm not the only person to have seen it, I'm hoping to find someone who has come across similar behavior and may be able to suggest what to do to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: @BDL Thanks. Based on comments here and some checks on other computers, as well as the info on the site where I originally obtained this script, this strange pattern does not seem to appear on other people's computers. OK I will "dig in" and try adding a real material and/or shader and see if this goes away.

Comment: I can't seem to get GLUT working on my machine, but your non-GLUT earlier version gives me your artifacts for sure on Windows 10, so it is not unique to your computer! I can mess with the artifact by changing the `zNear` parameter of `gluPerspective`. I think something funny is going on in your `resize` method, but not quite sure what yet...

Comment: You might want to take a look [here](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/depthbuffer.htm) to get some mathematical insight into why your `zNear` plane choice is reducing the precision of your depth buffer and giving you those dark stair-step artifacts.

Comment: @CodeSurgeon OK today I have set aside some time to work on this and look into the depth buffer issue. In the end I hope to have a much better understanding how OpenGL works. Thank you for taking the time to run the script and report back that you can reproduce the problem!